# Can't set default timezone in PHP

Tags: php, timezone, php-ini

I've set this in my php.ini file, and restarted php5-fpm process

```
date.timezone = "UTC"
```

But phpinfo() script still shows this:

```
date.timezone   America/New_York    America/New_York
```

`phpinfo()` also shows that correct ini file is being used.

I've restarted - but problem persisted. Then I did:

```
sudo service nginx stop
sudo service apache2 start
```

and date.timezone is correct when mod-php (apache2) is in use instead of fcgi that is php in nginx.

Comment: Make sure you updated the correct php.ini... ofttimes there's more than one on a server. You can find the correct one using phpinfo()

Comment: um. yes. - I did check that correct file is used prior to asking.  - it's in my question actually.

Comment: Is it possible that the script itself is overriding the php.ini value for the timezone?

Comment: I'm testing from cli also. file only contains this: echo PHP_EOL . 'timezone: ' . date_default_timezone_get();

Comment: never mind. it works in cli mode. It still however doesn't work in fpm mode.

Comment: I had a very similar problem, except with EasyPHP - so for future Googlers, the problem is in `[easyphp]/conf_files/httpd.conf` on line 1022.

Comment: Thanks for the pool.d value. I couldn't remember the syntax, fixed me right up.

Comment: @Stann - This question is kinda old and you may have figured it out alright. But if you haven't, you needed to restart the php-fpm pool. I had to run `/etc/init.d/php-fpm-5.5 restart` to get this to work on a CentOS system. Restarting nginx alone wouldn't help.

Answer (score 7):

You probably edited the wrong `php.ini`. See `php_info()` (or `php -i` for the cli interpreter) which one is used. For example on ubuntu (and probably other linux distributions) its `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` for the cli-interpreter, `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini/` for the one used by Apaches `mod_php` and `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` used by `php5-cgi` (which is used by `nginx`).

Comment: Yep. I thought of that. So I actually change date.timezone in all php.ini config files: cli, apache2, cgi, fpm. It does work correctly with cli and apache2. it doesn't in fpm.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be be with php-fpm processes that lingers around and refers to the old php.ini file settings. 
This worked for me:

Get the process ids for php-fpm

```
root@thiru:/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d# ps aux | head -1 && ps aux | grep php-fpm | grep -v grep
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     32650  0.0  0.5  86624 17032 ?        Ss   21:44   0:00    php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)                    
www-data 32652  0.0  0.1  86624  4700 ?        S    21:44   0:00 php-fpm: pool www                                                       
www-data 32653  0.0  0.1  86624  4704 ?        S    21:44   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

Kill the processes. Starting with the master.

```
kill -9 32650
kill -9 32652
kill -9 32653
```

Start php-fpm using the init script

```
service php5-fpm start or /etc/init.d/php5-fpm start
```

Comment: That help :) But a "sudo service php5-fpm restart" was enough for me :)

Answer (score 2):

List of supported timezone values: http://php.net/timezones

Comment: "UTC" is actually on the list you provided. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php)

Comment: UTC - in others, i have checked it prior to asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

In my installation BY DEFAULT I had realy weird configuration. File /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf had such a setting at the end of the file

```
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = UTC
```

It lead to timezone setting being ignored in php.ini and default system timezone being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Check your FPM Installation, if you have a pool with a active chroot!

If you have a chroot environment, you need to copy the file /etc/localtime (symlink to /usr/share/zoneinfo/xyz) and the directory /usr/share/zoneinfo to your chroot.

Possible Error-Messages:

```
Fatal error: phpinfo(): Timezone database is corrupt - this should *never* happen!  
Warning: phpinfo(): Invalid date.timezone value ‘UTC’, we selected the timezone ‘UTC’ for now.
```

See https://serverfault.com/questions/413293/php-fpm-chroot-jail-corrupts-timezone-db